# how to send data from react app to a local rest api

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, axios

I am sending data from a react app to an api using `axios.post` method. Everything is in localhost.
the database gets a new document created everytime I make a post request which means there is no communication problem but the data fields are not created for example my schema has the values of weight, price, color but the new document created only has the `_id` field and nothing else.

```
  addAnimal(){
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/animals', this.state.newAnimal).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }
```

I am not getting any error and the response is also successful

Here is the form where the user enters the data:

```
<ModalBody>
              <Form.Label for="title">Animal:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" id="title" name="title" value={this.state.newAnimal.title} onChange={(e)=>{
                var { newAnimal } = this.state;
                newAnimal.title = e.target.value;
                this.setState({newAnimal});
              }} />

              <Form.Label for="weight">Weight:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" id="weight" value={this.state.newAnimal.weight} onChange={(e)=>{
                var { newAnimal } = this.state;
                newAnimal.weight = e.target.value;
                this.setState({newAnimal});
              }} />

              <Form.Label for="color">Color:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" id="color" value={this.state.newAnimal.color} onChange={(e)=>{
                var { newAnimal } = this.state;
                newAnimal.color = e.target.value;
                this.setState({newAnimal});
              }}/>

              <Form.Label for="price">Price:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" id="price" value={this.state.newAnimal.price} onChange={(e)=>{
                var { newAnimal } = this.state;
                newAnimal.price = e.target.value;
                this.setState({newAnimal});
              }} />
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button onClick={()=>{this.handleModal()}}>Cancel</Button>
              <Button onClick={this.addAnimal.bind(this)} >Save</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
```

the `newAnimal` object that I am sending as data has all the fields data but when the database is updated with a document that document only has an id and nothing else.
this is how the `newAnimal` object looks like when I console.log

> {title: "ksjdh", weight: "8789", color: "khjds", price: "9879"}

but the document that is created in the database is empty

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please update your question with more information. As it stands, there is no way for us to help what's wrong as you haven't posted what the server code looks like, what's inside `this.state.newAnimal`, etc

Comment: Could you please paste your back-end code here, seems that you have a problem there and not with the fron-end part

Comment: No, i checked my api with postman, the api is working fine when i add documents using postman, its just not working with react

Comment: I have no idea about axios but are the values being passed in the HTTP post?  You should be able to see the data object in the network request panel in Chrome or whatever browser you're using.

Comment: ok I think this is a issue related to parsing, when i console log the data just before sending it is ok but when i console log the data at the server side it gets an empty object. however when i use JSON.stringify before sending then I get something like this on the server side: { '{"title":"skdj","weight":"askj","color":"askdj","price":"askdj"}': '' }  whereas it should be something like this: { weight: '500',
  title: 'kdhkjsk',
  color: 'kajhkd',
  price: 'akjsdk' }